# 51 degrees not activating

Tags: vb.net, 51degrees

I'am using 51degrees premium version. I have payd 2 licences to use it with two production servers on multiple hosts(web sites).

Servers are IIS6 web servers
I have root which have App_Data folder (network has full persmisions on that) . 
I have FiftyOne.Foundation.dll on bin folder, downloaded from https://51degrees.codeplex.com/releases/view/133106

I have 51Degrees.config (above part of it) on root of my site

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="fiftyOne">
      <section name="log" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Configuration.LogSection, FiftyOne.Foundation" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" restartOnExternalChanges="false" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <section name="redirect" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Configuration.RedirectSection, FiftyOne.Foundation" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" restartOnExternalChanges="false" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <section name="detection"  type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.Configuration.DetectionSection, FiftyOne.Foundation" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" restartOnExternalChanges="false" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <section name="imageOptimisation" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Configuration.ImageOptimisationSection, FiftyOne.Foundation" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" restartOnExternalChanges="false" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections> 
  <fiftyOne>
<log logFile="~/App_Data/Log.txt" logLevel="Debug"/> 
   <detection binaryFilePath="~/App_Data/51Degrees-Premium.dat"/>
   <imageOptimisation enabled="false" maxWidth="1000" maxHeight="1000" widthParam="width" heightParam="height" factor="1" />
```

web-config has this:

```
  <httpModules>   
  <add name="Detector" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.DetectorModule, FiftyOne.Foundation"/>    
</httpModules>
```

I have lic file on bin folder which has my lisence file on it.

The problem is that I can not get anything to error log (log.txt) the file does not even exists. I can not get 51Degrees-Premium.dat downloaded to app_data directory.

I have another site on same server (much higher volume of users), which has identical settings to this one and that site is donwnloadin new dat file and making log-file.

Where do I go wrong with this?

The working one has log like this:

```
2014-10-29T10:39:26.1560896Z - 6392 - Debug - Initialising redirection module
2014-10-29T10:39:57.0154646Z - 3012 - Debug - Disposing Redirection Module
2014-10-29T10:39:57.2967146Z - 3012 - Debug - Disposing Detector Module
2014-10-29T10:39:59.8904646Z - 6392 - Debug - Disposing Redirection Module
2014-10-29T10:39:59.8904646Z - 6392 - Debug - Disposing Detector Module
2014-10-29T10:40:07.4373396Z - 3012 - Debug - Bandwidth monitoring 'False'
2014-10-29T10:40:07.4373396Z - 3012 - Debug - Image Optimisation 'False'
2014-10-29T10:40:07.4373396Z - 3012 - Debug - Profile Override 'False'
2014-10-29T10:40:07.4373396Z - 3012 - Debug - Initialising redirection module
2014-10-29T10:41:27.0184008Z - 3012 - Debug - Disposing Redirection Module
2014-10-29T10:41:27.2996526Z - 3012 - Debug - Disposing Detector Module
2014-10-29T10:43:49.0965464Z - 3012 - Debug - Could not write device information to URL 'http://devices.51degrees.mobi/new.ashx'. Exception 'The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.'
2014-10-29T10:45:37.5685412Z - 3012 - Debug - Bandwidth monitoring 'False'
2014-10-29T10:45:37.5685412Z - 3012 - Debug - Image Optimisation 'False'
2014-10-29T10:45:37.5685412Z - 3012 - Debug - Profile Override 'False'
2014-10-29T10:45:37.5685412Z - 3012 - Debug - Initialising redirection module
2014-10-29T10:45:37.6154162Z - 3012 - Debug - Bandwidth monitoring 'False'
2014-10-29T10:45:37.6154162Z - 3012 - Debug - Image Optimisation 'False'
2014-10-29T10:45:37.6154162Z - 3012 - Debug - Profile Override 'False'
2014-10-29T10:45:37.6154162Z - 3012 - Debug - Initialising redirection module
```

But even ths working one is working kind of odd. if I make this:
Request.Browser("IsMobile")  It returns only empty value, not true or false

**What is going wrong and how to fix this?**

Comment: Surely paying for two licenses entitles you to technical support from the vendor?

Comment: Hi, for technical questions/problems it's best to contact 51Degrees directly as you will get a faster response. More to the point, have you tried updating to the latest version (3.1.9.3)? There have been a few bug fixes since 3.1.6.6.

Comment: Main problem was quite old paltform we used (server 2003 32-bit). With news servers all seems to be working.

Comment: I have the same behavior,  I can't get it to activate,  and no log nothing... guess i'll contact them directly!